# Dual monitors using different Nvidia GPUs not working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors

In my machine I have two Nvidia graphics cards. I am running Ubuntu 14.0.4.2 x64.

My primary card is a GTX650, and my secondary card is an 8600GT.

I would like to have dual monitors, with one monitor per card. (Yes, I know the GTX650 has 3 outputs, but I need the S-Video on the 8600GT)

By dual monitors I mean the statndard setup where you can drag a window from one to the other.

When I hook up the second monitor to the 8600GT, nothing happens. So I went into the Nvidia Control Panel and enabled it. After restarting, I can move my cursor to the second screen, but the cursor is a white "X". Some googling revealed this means that there is an X server running on it. But I don't understand why it can't behave just like I had plugged another monitor into my GTX650.

By the way, this works fine with the open-source drivers.

Similar to this: [Can't get Dual Monitors to work on different GPUs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63933/can-not-get-dual-monitors-to-work-on-different-gpus?rq=1)

Comment: Nobody has any ideas whatsoever? :(